Not sure what to do with this but here is a highranking question with the wrong answer that can have horrible results
Would seriously suggest removing this answer since it's ranking on google, is wrong and really risk fucking up somones backup... Not sure who should know about this...
Where can I view my HD wallet seed in bitcoin core 13.2

thanks for raising awareness. 
I'm going to add a warning to both of these answers. If you already have the privilege to do so, downvoting the answers would be proper, too. (I've done so already.)
Optimally, someone would post the correct answer.

Somone already wrote a correct answer.

Why would you not just delete or remove the body of the answer rather than just leave a health warning?
